# Python 2.7 - tkinter update from other file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to update tkinter entry from other file and it's not working.
For example I have two files, one of them is GUI.py and the second is lib.py.
I try to update entry in GUI.py from lib.py and I am getting the following error:

> "yourName.delete(0, END)
>
> NameError: global name 'yourName' is not defined"

My code looks like:

### File 1 - GUI.py

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.title("GUI Example")

app.geometry('200x100+200+200')

tv = StringVar(None)

yourName = Entry(app, textvariable=tv)

yourName.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text="click here", command=beenClicked).pack(side="bottom",padx=15,pady=15)

app.mainloop()
```

### File 2 - lib.py

```
def beenClicked():

    yourName.delete(0, END)

    yourName.insert(0, "Eran Z")
```

Thanks, Eran

Comment: how do you import one file into another ?

Comment: By using import lib command

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that GUI.py uses stuff from lib.py and vice versa, so the easier solution would be to put everything in the same file. But you obviously want to keep the two files otherwise you wouldn't ask this question.

So for this to work, the lib.py module should not depend on any object defined in the main file GUI.py:

**lib.py**

```
def beenClicked(entry):
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    entry.insert(0, "Eran Z")
```

**GUI.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
from lib import beenClicked

app = Tk()
app.title("GUI Example")
app.geometry('200x100+200+200')

tv = StringVar(None)

yourName = Entry(app, textvariable=tv)
yourName.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text="click here", command=lambda: beenClicked(yourName)).pack(side="bottom",padx=15,pady=15)

app.mainloop()
```

So the function `beenClicked` acts on an entry given as argument, not on the entry created in GUI.py, so there is no problem of existence of the entry.
But this means that I need to use a lamdba function to pass `yourName` in argument to `beenClicked` in the button command.